# Recuperar arquivo do input file bootstrap

Tags: html, html5, input, bootstrap

Existe alguma diferença na hora de recuperar o arquivo do Input File no Bootstrap para o HTML comum? 
estou usando o seguinte código:

e recuperando/imprimindo na outra pagina com
echo $fileTamanho = $_FILES['file']['size'];

ja tentei tanto com GET como por POST e da o mesmo erro de

Undefined index: file in...

Eu uso o mesmo código em outro projeto sem o bootstrap e funciona normalmente, alguém sabe oq pode estar acontecendo?

OBS: os outros parametros eu recupero normalmente, só o input que da error.

Answer (score 0):

Você está definindo o *enctype* como *multipart/form-data* para permitir o envio de arquivo ?
Exemplo:

```
<form action="foo.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form-horizontal" role="form">
```

Para recuperar utilizando *php* pode usar:

```
$meuArquivo = $_FILES['arquivo']['name']
```

Onde ['arquivo'] deve ser o o que está dentro de ***name=""*** no *form*.